# Show 2 square pictures above eachother, taking 50% of the width of the screen

Tags: android, image

I am a webdeveloper, and I am very lost in all the Android screen settings for aligning content. I've seen weight, gravity, scaletypes of the image etc. etc.)
I hope I can make my intentions clear, and that it's possible to fullfill them.

In this picture of a phone screen, I have 2 square pictures (the purple and the green one).
[image]

What I want to accomplish is that the width of the pictures always take up 50% of the screen width, and that it is centered (so the margin left and margin right is 25%).

So let's say you have a 600*800 screen, the width should be 300 pixels and the margin left and right would be 150 pixels (or better 25%). On a 768*1024 screen the width should be 384 pixels.
The height should follow that size (I've tried a lot of code, and the best result was that the width was sort of a pertentage, with 3 relative layouts in a lineair layout, but then only the width was correct, but the height wasn't)

Depending on your screen size it could be that the height of the two images together would be higher than the screen and a scrollbar would be neccessary)

Comment: Can not agree with you. Don't even know what you mean with 'using the support library'.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap them in PercentRelativeLayout and fix their width 50%. set their height equal to their width in Java when the view gets populated

Comment: There is no `PercentRelativeLayout ` in my Eclipse "pallete" when designing the form. ...confused... Is my Eclipse too old?

Comment: add compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.0.0' in your build.gradle. Dont know how to add libraries in eclipse. you will most probably have to download a jar and add dependency. Switch to android studio for better experience. also here is a tutorial on percent relative layout    http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/know-percent-support-library/en. This library was introduced in design support library version 23 by google. it also supports margins in percents. Read tutorial to know more